# How to add css code to html?

Tags: php, html, css, button, format

I am struggling to add a css button code to my html document.

Here is the code:

```
.button {
border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
background: #65a9d7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d),to(#65a9d7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
padding: 5px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Georgia, Serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
border-top-color: #28597a;
background: #28597a;
color: #ccc;
}
.button:active {
border-top-color: #1b435e;
background: #1b435e;
}
```

Now I am wanting to add this to this html code but as I said I am struggling. The format of my code is roughly like this :

```
<li><a href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>">Terms</a></li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see a class named `button` in your CSS but not in your HTML. Have you given any tag in your HTML a class of `button`?

Comment: If you are asking how to add a css file then you should google it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
    <a href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" class="button">Terms</a>
</li>
```

(assuming the class is accessible within the context of the link).

Comment: I have done that now but when I put the css code into the html document it shows up on my website?

Comment: If the css is in the html document then it will show up on the page source. But if it's showing up on the actual page then make sure you put <style></style> tags around the css (as demonstrated in @Amal Murali's excellently detailed answer). If what you're trying to do is keep it off the page source you can use an external stylesheet as demonstrated by Amal as well. Is there anything still unclear/confusing?

Answer (score 1):

You've made the CSS style definitions, but you haven't assigned that class to your element.

Try this:

```
<li><a class="button" href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" >Terms</a></li>
```

The above code assumes that you've loaded / defined the style definitions in your HTML page. If it's an HTML page, you can either:

- use `<style>` tags
- use an external stylesheet

### 1. Using `<style>` tags:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    /* CSS Definitions go here */

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <li><a class="button" href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" >Terms</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

### 2. Using an external stylesheet

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <li><a class="button" href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" >Terms</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Working demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/KLnQ9/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but where do I put the button css code? Inbetween what variables?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class to the thing you want to be styled.

```
<li><a href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" class="button">Terms</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I put the button css code? Inbetween what variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are not adding a class to your ahref link tag, to add a class to any HTML element is simple add the following code:
`class="{class name}"`
*There is a convention with classes and id that many web developer follow as well. 
Class are for element that repeat while id are not. So if you have many buttons it would be a class whilst you may only have one main id to go along with the button.*

You should have also loaded your style sheet.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="name_of_your_stylesheet.css"/>`

Knowing that you problem is that you created a nice button style but didn't add a css class name to your element the correct solution is:
`<li><a href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" class="button">Terms</a></li>`
take a notice of the class name that is added to the html element.

Here is a working demo of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/NuTSw/

Thanks

any follow up question, tweet me on my twitter: @[muhammad_khan40](https://twitter.com/muhammad_khan40)